# getting Jquery's datepicker to work with Django DateField form

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, jquery-ui, datepicker

I am following a tutorial on using jquery datepicker at http://hexonio.com/blog/2012/03/07/calendar-picker-django-forms/.

My form is a simple DateField:

```
class CalendarForm(forms.Form):
    field1 = forms.DateField()
```

I installed the datepicker as instructed:

```
   ...
    $(function() {
        $( "id_field1" ).datepicker();
    });

</script>
```

The tutorial says to install jquery locally, so from http://jqueryui.com/download I picked 1.11.14 as it said "stable", and unzipped it to a jquery folder in media:

```
cchilders@cody_pc:~/projects/django_projects/bookmarks_tracker/media/jquery/jquery-ui-1.11.4.custom$ ls
external    jquery-ui.css      jquery-ui.min.js             jquery-ui.theme.css
images      jquery-ui.js       jquery-ui.structure.css      jquery-ui.theme.min.css
index.html  jquery-ui.min.css  jquery-ui.structure.min.css
```

I installed all of them in 'base.html' to be safe:

`base.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>

        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Sitename</title>

        <link type="text/css" href="/media/jquery/jquery-ui-1.11.4.custom/jquery-ui.css" rel="Stylesheet" />
        <link type="text/css" href="/media/jquery/jquery-ui-1.11.4.custom/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="Stylesheet" />
        <link type="text/css" href="/media/jquery/jquery-ui-1.11.4.custom/jquery-ui.theme.css" rel="Stylesheet" />
        <link type="text/css" href="/media/jquery/jquery-ui-1.11.4.custom/jquery-ui.theme.min.css" rel="Stylesheet" />
        <link type="text/css" href="/media/jquery/jquery-ui-1.11.4.custom/jquery-ui.structure.css" rel="Stylesheet" />
        <link type="text/css" href="/media/jquery/jquery-ui-1.11.4.custom/jquery-ui.structure.min.css" rel="Stylesheet" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/media/jquery/jquery-ui-1.11.4.custom/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/media/jquery/jquery-ui-1.11.4.custom/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

        <!-- Load javascript libraries -->
        <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/js/select2.min.js"></script> 

        <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="/media/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

        <link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <!-- <link href="static/select2/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src="static/select2/js/select2.min.js"></script> -->

        <!-- semantic -->
        <link href="https://cdnjs.com/libraries/semantic-ui" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

I have installed all the files there into base, but the datepicker does not work. When I comment out `<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`, no jquery at all on the page works. So the jquery I unzipped isn't working, but I think it finds the files with a 304 redirect:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Sep/2015 16:32:21] "GET /silo/ HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Sep/2015 16:32:21] "GET /media/jquery/jquery-ui-1.11.4.custom/jquery-ui.css HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Sep/2015 16:32:21] "GET /media/jquery/jquery-ui-1.11.4.custom/jquery-ui.min.css HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Sep/2015 16:32:21] "GET /media/jquery/jquery-ui-1.11.4.custom/jquery-ui.theme.css HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Sep/2015 16:32:21] "GET /media/jquery/jquery-ui-1.11.4.custom/jquery-ui.theme.min.css HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Sep/2015 16:32:21] "GET /media/jquery/jquery-ui-1.11.4.custom/jquery-ui.structure.css HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Sep/2015 16:32:21] "GET /media/jquery/jquery-ui-1.11.4.custom/jquery-ui.structure.min.css HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Sep/2015 16:32:21] "GET /media/jquery/jquery-ui-1.11.4.custom/jquery-ui.js HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Sep/2015 16:32:21] "GET /media/css/main.css HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Sep/2015 16:32:21] "GET /media/jquery/jquery-ui-1.11.4.custom/jquery-ui.min.js HTTP/1.1" 304 -
```

The form is `calendar_form` in the template...

`silo.html`:

```
{% if articles %}

        <div style="width:94%;">
            {% if tags %}
                <div class="help-text">
                    <p>You can filter your articles by tags. Articles with the most tags matched come first, and all articles that have at least one tag will show up.</p>
                </div>

                <div>
                    <h4>Tags</h4>
                    <form id="category_form" method="post" action="{% url 'index:silo' %}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                          {% csrf_token %}

                          <section id="multiple" class="row">
                              <div class="col-md-8">
                                  <span>
                                      <select  style="width:90%;" multiple="multiple" id="selected_tags" name="selected_tags">
                                          {% for tag in tags %}        
                                              <option value="{{tag.slug}}">{{tag.name}}</option>
                                          {% endfor %}
                                      </select>                
                                  </span>
                               </div>
                          </section>
                          <br/>
                          {{ calendar_form }}
                          <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search"/>
                          <br/>
                    </form>
                    <br/>
                </div>
            {% endif %}
```

I checked that registering it in jquery as `id_field1` was correct to be sure, and it is `id_field1`.

The confusing part is how my other jquery items work (toggle, swapping classes, swapping text, ajax request, select2 and so on), but this datepicker doesn't.

How can I get this datepicker to work as a calendar you can scroll through and pick dates like normal, with either inline or externally linked jquery?

Thank you

[image]

This console errors are as follows:

Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined 
from my jquery-ui.js

Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined 
from my jquery-ui.min.js

Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function from the page accessed (http://127.0.0.1:8000/silo/)

If I comment out my local jquery files and leave the cloudfare one, it still says "datepicker is not a function" but the docs say it is http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/

[image]

Putting

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/media/jquery/jquery-ui-1.11.4.custom/jquery-ui.min.js"></script> 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/media/jquery/jquery-ui-1.11.4.custom/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

at the top before the CSS causes a boatload of problems:

[image]

Comment: Load the jquery.min.js first and then the plugin libraries afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

You are hitting the console error because you are loading jquery.min.js after jquery-ui.min.js. If you swap the order it should work.  In general, since a lot of plugins rely on jquery, you should put it at the top of your JS declarations.